# How to translate using shaders and matrices?

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I'm am using LWJGL and shaders to try and translate everything I'm drawing within my shader program.
I am using a 4 by 4 matrix

```
1,0,0,x,
0,1,0,y,
0,0,1,z,
0,0,0,1
```

Where x,y,z are the values I am using to translate. Then I use

```
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex * transformMatrix
```

Where transformMatrix is a uniform mat4 which I get from the matrix above.
It translates x and y fine but not on the z axis (forward and back).

Is it the matrix or the shader method that's wrong? (or both)

How do I fix this so that it translates like `glTranslatef`? Thanks

Comment: You should probably not use the gl_ inputs (they are deprecated) an instead use glVertexAttribPointer and VBOs, and use proper uniforms

Comment: Beaker: that fixed the z axis translation but all x and y do now are skew.

Ratchet: Everything seems to be deprecated.. I moved onto shaders because glTranslatef was deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix itself looks ok. Remember that OpenGL uses column-major storage for matrices by default, so the elements for this matrix would be ordered like this when you specify it:

```
{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
 x,    y,    z,    1.0f}
```

If you want to stick with row-major order in your code, you can also specify `GL_TRUE` as the 3rd argument (*transpose*) of `glUniformMatrix4fv()`'.

It looks like you're stuck between two different levels of OpenGL. To put this in context, let me number some of the main evolution stages of OpenGL. The following is not official terminology, I just made it up.

- **Stage 1**: Fixed function pipeline. Rendering is performed purely by specifying state, and issuing draw commands. State includes the matrix stack, lighting and material attributes, etc.
- **Stage 2**: Programmable pipeline with fixed function attributes. Shaders are used to control the rendering, but fixed function state like the matrix stack is still used. This state is accessed using predefined variables in the GLSL code.
- **Stage 3**: Fully programmable. Fixed function state is not used anymore, and all input to shaders is specified with generic attributes and uniforms.

Matching this up with OpenGL versions:

- OpenGL 1.x is strictly using Stage 1.
- OpenGL 2.x code typically uses Stage 2, even though it is fully backwards compatible and still supports everything from Stage 1. It already has most of what is needed for Stage 3.
- OpenGL 3.x and later support only Stage 3 with the Core Profile (which was introduced in 3.2). All the fixed function aspects from Stage 1 and Stage 2 are only available in the Compatibility Profile.

Your code fragment suggests that you were using Stage 2, and are making attempts to move to Stage 3. In the process, you created a questionable mix between the two. Depending on which direction you want to go, the solution is different.

### Use of Fixed Function State

As long as you're using the matrices from the fixed function matrix stack in your shader (`gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`), the easiest solution is really to use it fully.

So to translate, you call `glTranslatef()`, which adds a translation to your model-view matrix, which is then accessed in the GLSL code with `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` and similar built-in variables.

### Hybrid of Fixed Function and Uniform

With the approach you are trying to use, the most reasonable solution is to multiply the additional translation matrix with the vector before the built-in `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`:

```
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * transformMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

You need to be aware that this applies the additional translation **before** all the other model transformations that you may have in the model-view transformations. Say you also specified a rotation with the fixed function call:

```
glRotatef(...);
```

This rotation is part of the model-view matrix, and will now be applied **after** the translation you added. So you will rotate the translated coordinates, which may not be what you want.

With this approach, there's no good way to apply the translation after your other model transforms. What you would basically need is this:

```
gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ViewMatrix * transformMatrix * gl_ModelMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

But since the View and Model matrices are combined in the fixed function state, this is not possible.

### No Fixed Function State

For full flexibility, and compatibility with the current Core Profile, you need to stop using fixed function state, and the corresponding GLSL built-in variables like `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`. To do this, you specify all matrices you need as uniform variables in the shader code. This gives you full control over what matrices you use, and how you apply them in the GLSL code.

For example, if you just need a translation, there's no need to use a full matrix. You can use a `vec3` for the uniform, and simply add it to the position vector.

The main downside of the fully programmable approach is that you can't use convenience functions like `glRotatef()`, `gluLookAt`, and `gluPerspective()` anymore. There are open source libraries that provide replacements, and it's also easy to write similar functions yourself if you're so inclined. You also don't have a matrix stack anymore, so you need some more logic in your own code if you're relying on a hierarchy of transformations.

Comment: That sounds a bit hard.. But I'm going to have to learn the no fixed function state way anyway. And thanks for the ordering of the matrices, that made it work but I guess I still more stuff to learn.